# List add() method error

Tags: hibernate, loops, for-loop, nested, addition

```
trainDetailFrom = (ArrayList<TrainDetail>) session.createQuery("from TrainDetail where Station = '"+this.getFrom()+"'").list();
trainDetailTo =(ArrayList<TrainDetail>) session.createQuery("from TrainDetail where Station = '"+this.getTo()+"'").list();
for(TrainDetail trainFrom:trainDetailFrom)
{
    for(TrainDetail trainTo:trainDetailTo)
    {
        if(trainFrom.getTrain()==trainTo.getTrain() &&trainFrom.getDistance()<trainTo.getDistance())
        {
            this.train.add(trainFrom.getTrain());
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to get train value on web page, when i run this action page it not provide train value i think train.add() not setting value. please help.

Comment: any exceptions ? what do you mean by: getTrain() ? what do you expect as result

Comment: what is the exception can u show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I have not initialize the `train` which is instance of `ArrayList<Train>` so I initialize as `train=new ArrayList<Train>();`

Answer (score 0):

If trains are not being added to the collection *train*, check:

- *trainDetailTo* and *trainDetailFrom* are not empty.
- Compare objects are the same using `equals`() (compares by value) instead of comparing using `==` (compares by reference).